# R SQLDF PIVOT FOR A DATA FRAME

Tags: r

I have a data.frame named as data6 on which i want to perform pivot. 
[image]
i have tried sqldf but after checking thoroughly still i couldn't find why this error is coming

**"Error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement) : near "(": syntax error"**

**sql statement: "Select * From (Select * From data6) PIVOT(sum([Qty]) FOR [GRNUOM] in ([con2],[con3],[con4],[Con15],[Con2],[Con3],[Con4])"**

Using recast/dcast function it can be done but as a new user i don't know how to do it. even i don't know what is difference between recast & dcast.

I know it's a lot of questions but if anyone help me out on this

Comment: You may want to check [tidyr](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr) package, `gather` and `spread` function.

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sqldf` package by default uses SQLite as the underlying database, and therefore the `PIVOT` syntax you are using won't work.  While you might be able to change the underlying database to SQL Server, you could also just use an ANSI standard pivot query:

```
sql <- "SELECT \"Style Name\",
            SUM(CASE WHEN GRNUOM = 'con2' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END) AS con2,
            SUM(CASE WHEN GRNUOM = 'con3' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END) AS con3,
            SUM(CASE WHEN GRNUOM = 'con4' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END) AS con4,
            SUM(CASE WHEN GRNUOM = 'Con15' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END) AS Con15,
            SUM(CASE WHEN GRNUOM = 'Con2' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END) AS Con2,
            SUM(CASE WHEN GRNUOM = 'Con3' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END) AS Con3,
            SUM(CASE WHEN GRNUOM = 'Con4' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END) AS Con4
FROM data6
GROUP BY \"Style Name\""

result <- sqldf(sql)
```

I am not certain if `con2` and `Con2` would actually be recognized as separate column names.  You might have to put all column names in double quotes to make the above query work the way you expect.

Comment: The sums can be written `SUM(Qty * (GRNUOM = 'con2'))`